# clicking button disable it and store current datetime in database after date change button re active in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
<table id="rounded-corner">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%">ID</th>
      <th>Site Url</th>
      <th width="10%"></th>
      <th width="">Visit Sites</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['siteID'])) {
   $q = "INSERT INTO visited (userID, siteID, datetime)
        VALUES(".$_SESSION['id'].", ".$_POST['siteID'].", NOW())";
   $r = mysql_query($q);
   header('Location: index.php');
 }

  while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
 <form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['url']; ?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <?php
        $query1 = "SELECT datetime FROM visited WHERE `siteID` = ".$rows['id']." AND `userID` = ".$_SESSION['id']." LIMIT 1";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

        $difference=strtotime('tomorrow')-time();
        echo $difference;
        if($difference > 0){
        ?>
          <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Visit Now" id="btnVisit<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" />
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="siteID" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" />
          <input type="submit" value="Visit Now" id="btnVisit<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" />
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    </form>
 <?php
  }
 ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Have some buttons in a page. Let's say user's already registerd. Login user's can daily view this page and click these links.When button clicked store userid, and site id, and current datetime in visited table. All buttons are now disabled until tomorrow midnight. As soon as date change all buttons reactivate.

tables are follow:

**users**: id, name, password

**sites**: id, url

**visited**: id, userid, siteid, datetime

thanks

Comment: What code do you have so far? Is there going to be javascript involved?

Comment: no i am just using pure php mysql.

Comment: so I take it the user_button table takes in the button click's datetime in the datetime field?

Comment: first i need to figure out how to check today is still 14th and the button still disabled after enter 15th button reactivate ...

Comment: why not just do a difference of dates, the one in the database vs. today's date. If the difference >= 1 day, reactivate the button.

Comment: if you show us some of your code, it'll be easier to put it into context

Comment: Not seeing a question mark here. So what's the question?

Comment: my question is clear i want to know how to calculate date is today or tomorrow then this date base i will disable enable button.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a date difference between the date in the database and today's date:

https://www.php.net/date_diff

```
    $visited = date_create($row1['datetime']);
    $today = date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

    $diff = date_diff($visited, $today );
    echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

this should have a full day (24hrs) elapse before the result is +1 day.

Comment: then I suggest being more specific with your question, and adding sample code that you've got so far if you want more detailed help

Comment: ok i have share some of my code that is i am currently working... plz check and help me... where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're storing in the datetime, the last time they clicked the button, then just in your code where you display the button, do a check to see if today's date is greater than the date stored in the db.  If it is, then display the button; Otherwise, disable the button.

You can have your SQL statement be something like this to get the date from the DB:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) FROM user_button WHERE userid = 'XXXXX' AND buttonid = 'YYYYY';
```

And then compare it against yesterday's datelike this:

```
$date_yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('yesterday'));

if ($date_from_db > $date_yesterday) {
   // SHOW FULL BUTTON
}
else {
    // SHOW DISABLED BUTTON
}
```

Comment: yes i am reach that point but problem is how to compare tomorrow is arise and button re active.

Comment: in database stored today's current datetime (2014-02-14 11:10:40) so we need check until (2014-02-15 00:00:00) that point we enable the button again...

Comment: so you don't want a full day to have passed, but for the day to have changed only